# Get the primary category of the previous product in the product archive loop

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to get the details of a previous product in the loop. For instance if we have the following list of products:

- Product A (Category 1)
- Product B (Category 1)
- Product C (Category 1)
- Product D (Category 2)

Would it be possible to access the category of the previous product, then if the category is different to the current product execute a function.

In the example above when we get to Product D, the change in category would trigger a section divider in the loop.